# PostgreSQL 10 public schema default ownership conflicts with pg_restore --clean

Tags: postgresql

On a PostgreSQL instance of v10.21, we created `appuser` for the operations regarding the application, and we don't usually have the credential of the superuser `postgres`.

It seems that `postgres` owns the `public` schema inside any database by default, even if the database is created and owned by `appuser`. This system behaviour conflicts with `pg_restore --clean`.

The `--clean` option means to clean before restoring, so when the process comes to dropping the `public` schema, it encounters errors saying `could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of schema public`. See more details in the screenshot below.

I am wondering:

- As a quick dirty workaround, should we just ignore the errors?
- Or, should we get the superuser to change the owner to `appuser`? This action will suppress the errors but we don't know whether there is any complication after changing the system's default settings.

**Screenshot of `pg_restore --clean` run-time errors:**

```
...
... dropping other objects in the public schema ...
...

    pg_restore: dropping SEQUENCE OWNED BY activity_id_seq
    pg_restore: dropping SEQUENCE activity_id_seq
    pg_restore: dropping TABLE activity
    pg_restore: dropping COMMENT SCHEMA public
    pg_restore: dropping SCHEMA public
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3; 2615 2200 SCHEMA public postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of schema public
        Command was: DROP SCHEMA public;
    pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "public"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
        Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;
    pg_restore: creating COMMENT "SCHEMA public"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4429; 0 0 COMMENT SCHEMA public postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of schema public
        Command was: COMMENT ON SCHEMA public IS 'standard public schema';
    pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.activity"
    pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.activity_id_seq"

...
... creating other objects in the public schema ...
...

   WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 3
```

Comment: I've made our application user the owner of the `public` schema. (In fact, we often just dropped and recreated the `public` schema)

Comment: 1) What is the complete `pg_dump` command being used? 2) What is the complete `pg_restore` command being used? 3) Are you using the Postgres 10 version of pg_dump/pg_restore to do this? 4) Have you tried using `-C` with `-c` to drop the database first and then restore? If you do this be sure you point `-d` at a database other then the one you are restoring. Add answers as update to question.

Comment: Hi, @AdrianKlaver. From the other comments, it seems to be a common system behaviour not specific to a particular use case: the superuser `postgres` owns schema `public` despite the database's ownership. However, you may refer to [this post](https://discourse.metabase.com/t/how-to-migrate-metabase-to-another-postgresql-instance/21238/3) for the sample commands to reproduce the issue. Also, dropping the database is not a good option either because the `appuser` is not supposed to have permission to create databases. I hope the information helps.

Comment: What happens if you drop the `--no-owner` on the restore? I cannot replicate this behavior.

Comment: My attempts where on a Postgres 14 instance. Now there have been a lot of changes wrt to the `public`  schema in recent versions, so this may be version specific.

Comment: Hi, @AdrianKlaver, our specific scenario needs to keep `--no-owner` in the command call, and the PostgreSQL version is 10 for both the server and client, so we didn't have a chance to verify if the issue disappeared in version 14. We have already bypassed the issue with the workaround suggested by other replies, so it's not blocking anymore.